# Обтекание картинки текстом в OpenXML Word

Tags: c#, openxml

Есть код с MSDN по вставке картинки в документ

```
public void InsertAPicture(WordprocessingDocument document, string fileName)
    {
            MainDocumentPart mainPart = document.MainDocumentPart;
            ImagePart imagePart = mainPart.AddImagePart(ImagePartType.Jpeg);
            using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open))
            {
                imagePart.FeedData(stream);
            }
            AddImageToBody(mainPart, mainPart.GetIdOfPart(imagePart));
    }

    private void AddImageToBody(MainDocumentPart mainPart, string relationshipId)
    {
        // Define the reference of the image.
        var element =
             new Drawing(
                 new DW.Anchor(
                     new DW.WrapNone())
                 { BehindDoc = true },
                 new DW.Inline(
                     new DW.Extent() { Cx = 990000L, Cy = 792000L },
                     new DW.EffectExtent()
                     {
                         LeftEdge = 0L,
                         TopEdge = 0L,
                         RightEdge = 0L,
                         BottomEdge = 0L
                     },
                     new DW.DocProperties()
                     {
                         Id = (UInt32Value)1U,
                         Name = "Picture 1",
                         
                     },
                     
                     new DW.NonVisualGraphicFrameDrawingProperties(
                         new A.GraphicFrameLocks() { NoChangeAspect = true }),
                     new A.Graphic(
                         new A.GraphicData(
                             new PIC.Picture(
                                 new PIC.NonVisualPictureProperties(
                                     new PIC.NonVisualDrawingProperties()
                                     {
                                         Id = (UInt32Value)0U,
                                         Name = "New Bitmap Image.jpg"
                                     },
                                     new PIC.NonVisualPictureDrawingProperties()),
                                 new PIC.BlipFill(
                                     new A.Blip(
                                         new A.BlipExtensionList(
                                             new A.BlipExtension()
                                             {
                                                 Uri =
                                                    "{28A0092B-C50C-407E-A947-70E740481C1C}"
                                             })
                                     )
                                     {
                                         Embed = relationshipId,
                                         CompressionState =
                                         A.BlipCompressionValues.Print
                                     },
                                     new A.Stretch(
                                         new A.FillRectangle())),
                                 new PIC.ShapeProperties(
                                     new A.Transform2D(
                                         new A.Offset() { X = 0L, Y = 0L },
                                         new A.Extents() { Cx = 990000L, Cy = 792000L }),
                                     new A.PresetGeometry(
                                         new A.AdjustValueList()
                                     )
                                     { Preset = A.ShapeTypeValues.Rectangle }))
                         )
                         { Uri = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture" })
                 )
                 {
                     DistanceFromTop = (UInt32Value)0U,
                     DistanceFromBottom = (UInt32Value)0U,
                     DistanceFromLeft = (UInt32Value)0U,
                     DistanceFromRight = (UInt32Value)0U,
                     EditId = "50D07946"
                 });

        // Append the reference to body, the element should be in a Run.
        Body bod = mainPart.Document.Body;
        foreach (Table t in bod.Descendants<Table>().Where(tbl => tbl.InnerText.Contains("Потребитель услуг")))
        {
            TableRow row = t.Elements<TableRow>().ElementAt(0);
            TableCell cell = row.Elements<TableCell>().ElementAt(1);
            cell.AppendChild(new Paragraph(new Run(element)));
        }
        //wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.AppendChild(new Paragraph(new Run(element)));
    }
```

Мне нужно обтекание текстом: "За текстом". Подскажите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Перед `Body bod = mainPart.Document.Body;` Вставить следующее:

```
DW.Anchor anchor1 = new DW.Anchor() { BehindDoc = false };
DW.WrapNone wrapNone1 = new DW.WrapNone();
anchor1.Append(wrapNone1);
element.Append(anchor1);
```